# What values need to be passed in (Version $subject) arguments in clearing the cache programmatically

Tags: magento2, cache

I am bit confused, I am using the below method to clear the cache in Magento 2 programmatically, this method has an argument, and what value I need to pass in it?

**method:**

```
**public function flushCache(Version $subject)**
    {
        $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
        
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
        }
        foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
            $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
        }
}
```

Comment: are you talking about which line from above code?

Comment: public function flushCache(Version $subject)
        {
            $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
            
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
            }
            foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
                $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
            }
    }

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya in the above snippet am asking about the first line, what attribute we need to pass in that.

Comment: Can you share complete file code on question.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i have updated my question please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work just fine if you remove that argument from the function and pass in nothing.

I have a similar script running on mine and it does not need a "Version" argument or object anywhere.

Edit:
So the final function should look like this:

```
public function flushCache()
{
        $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
        
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
        }
        foreach ($this->cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
            $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
        }
}
```